# Get a list of TextFields that are available during runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-identifiers, proteus

I'm using an android library called [Proteus](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/proteus#getting-started) which inflates layouts during run time with a JSON file we have sitting on our server. This library allows for data binding but my question is how can I get data out of these fields while using my app? I can't reference any of the identifiers of the layout because they don't exist during compilation. Is there a way to ignore the error in the statement when (R.id.input) doesn't actually exist until runtime?:

```
View view = inflater.infalte(R.layout.fragment_form, container, false);
TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.input);
```

Or possibly programmatically get a list of all available unique identifiers during runtime? Any info would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[proteus](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/proteus) generates view ids at runtime, unlike the `int` ids generated at compile time for Android XML layouts. Unlike Android the IDs of Views created by proteus are based on `String`, and the `R.id.<something>` will not work.

Proteus provides utility methods to find a view by it's `String` id.

Layout:

```
{
  "type": "TextView",
  "id": "myId"
}
```

Java:

```
View view = proteusView.getViewManager().findViewById("myId"); // can be null
```

The returned view can also be a `ProteusView`

Please refer to [the wiki](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/proteus/wiki/Proteus-View) for more information.

> The wiki is slightly outdated, the answer above is for `5.0.0-rc11` release and above. The wiki should be updated soon.